# requestPermissions() does NOT request permissions

Tags: android, permissions

I have specific permissions in my application that I validate before using them. I get permissions that I do not have grant access to and try to request them, but I do not see any request dialog whatsoever.

Code:

Activity that inherits AppCompatActivity.

```
private fun requestPermissions(missingPermissions: ArrayList<String>) {
    val permissionArray = arrayOfNulls<String>(missingPermissions.size)
    missingPermissions.toArray(permissionArray)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(permissionArray, 1) //android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
    }
}
```

On `onRequestPermissionsResult()` I receive that this permission was denied - no clue how.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"
    tools:node="replace"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"
    tools:node="replace"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WIFI_SERVICE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"
    tools:node="replace"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"
    tools:node="replace"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"
    tools:node="replace"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"
    tools:node="replace"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"
    tools:node="replace"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"
    tools:node="replace"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"
    tools:node="replace"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"
    tools:node="replace"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"
    tools:node="replace"/>
```

Why I cannot request specific permissions?

Comment: What does `permissionArray` contains add it with question .

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Comment: you should know more about normal and dangerous permissions

Comment: @Quicklearner "If the user checks the Never ask again box and taps Deny, the system no longer prompts the user if you later attempt to requests the same permission.". I did uninstall application. Does this still have the same effect? Well, I dont see reason why my permission is not requested with my provided code. How can I request permissions that I have denied before in past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
requestPermissions(permissionArray, 1) //android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
```

[`ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` is a `normal` permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_WIFI_STATE). You do not need to request it at runtime. You *do* need to request it in the manifest, and I don't see it there.